# Publish app with testflight framework

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, testflight, beta-testing

I think I know the answer but I want to confirm this. Is it okay to publish an app to Apple App Store (iOS) with TestFlight framework?

I surely know that Crashlytics framework can be used even in live apps but not sure about test flight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can go with this idea, as it will give crash report to you. Apple also provide crash reports for the live version of the apps.